# How to automatically backup SharePoint site collection or Site

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Hi
I know I can use power shell or central admin to backup SharePoint site collection or Site,is there a way to automate this process or I have to create a scheduled task that runs either power-shell or stsadm command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

normally what we use to do is create a batch file of stsadm commands for backup and associate it with windows scheduler job. and i think thats the best approach you can do the same for powershell scripts as well

Answer (score 1):

You can automate the backing of sharepoint site collection using SPTimer Job. 
Based on the schedule SPTimer will back your site collection/site periodically. 
Since SPTimer job is integrated with SharePoint this can be implemented easily.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this. It's descriptive.

http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2010/archive/2010/12/21/sharepoint-2010-cookbook-powershell-script-to-backup-a-site-collection-automatically.aspx